# Maximum count for top 10 frequencies in data table

Tags: r, count, data.table

I want to create a table of the 10 most frequent reasons people discontinue a course. There are around 2,000 responses to my discontinuation survey, with the dataset entitled 'Discontinued'. There are 35 categories to describe the 'Reason'. Currently I have been using the below code but this gives me the frequecy for all 35 discontinuation codes.

```
Discontinued[,list(Count= .N), by = reason][order(-Count)]
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.  What are the other columns?  It sounds like reason may not be the right grouping variable.

Comment: So just `Discontinued[,list(Count= .N), by = reason][order(-Count)][1:10]`?

Comment: sorted. [1:10] would have ticked the answer. new to this package.

Comment: @MrFlick: Why not post an answer that discusses that strategy? ... unless of course it's a duplicate.

Comment: @BondedDust Honestly i don't know if data.table has an easier way to do this, but this just he most basic of indexing. I'd hardly consider it a "strategy". Truthfully, I'm surprised that's all the OP needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data.table` way to sort is `setorder`. So instead of

```
Discontinued[,list(Count= .N), by = reason][order(-Count)][1:10]
```

it should be faster to use

```
setorder(Discontinued[, list(Count= .N), by = reason], -Count)[1L:10L]
```

Comment: when using `dt[order()]` it should automatically optimize it to data.table's faster solutions.